# autodoc: failed to import module 'routes' from module 'app_folder'

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, python-sphinx, autodoc

I am trying to use Sphinx and it's giving me errors. What am I missing here?

WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'routes' from module 'app_folder'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy'

conf.py

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../'))
```

functions.rst

```
Functions
=========

.. automodule:: app_folder.routes
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
```

[image]

Comment: Too many parent dirs: `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../'))`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was i was using virtualenv and installed the sphinx before the activating the virtualenv